# Something wrong with timed image changer

Tags: javascript

This is my code so far, I'm using Dreamweaver and it says there is something wrong with line 14 and I have no idea what is wrong with it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<body onload="function()">
<img id="img" src="file:///H|/My Pictures/Green.jpg" />
<head/>
<script>
var images = ["file:///H|/My Pictures/Green.jpg", "file:///H|/My Pictures/Orange.jpg", "file:///H|/My Pictures/Red.jpg", "file:///H|/My Pictures/RedOrange.jpg"];
var counter = 0

function function()
var img = document.getElementById("img");
img.src = images[x]
x++;
if(x >= images.length){
    x=0
    var timerid = setInterval(function(), 1000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It now says there is a problem with the function ending or `};`

```js
function functions(){
var img = document.getElementById("img");
img.src = images[x]
x++;

if(x >= images.length){
    x=0
        var timerid = setInterval(functions(), 1000);
};
```

Comment: Can't see your code mate.

Comment: Go read [ask], please.

Comment: I added an image instead of formating  my code

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please paste and format your code here. Do you exspect us to retype it from that image? Nobody will do that. What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

That error on line 14 is in fact caused by the line before.
It doesn't know what to do with line 14 because its missing a correct function definition.

You need to wrap the function body in a block, surrounded by curly braces

```
function myFunction() {
    /* code of the function body */
};
```

UPDATE: line 14 = `var img = document.getElementById("img");`

UPDATE: you should not call your function `function` as "function" is a reserved word.